# Can i render a react context this way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-context, conditional-rendering

Currently I have a context to return the verification status of a given user. This context is wrapping all the App.

I have one `UnAuthStatusProvider`:

```
const UnAuthStatusProvider:FC = ({ children }) => (
    <VerificationStatusContext.Provider value={{ loading: false, status: '', contracts: [] }}>
        {children}
    </VerificationStatusContext.Provider>
)
```

And also a `AuthVerificationStatusProvider`. The only difference is that on the `AuthVerificationStatusProvider` I have the necessary queries to do so. Unfortunately, the library required to use on this project does not allow me to establish a condition before fetching the data. So I my idea was to use this on a conditional way like this:

```
export const VerificationStatusProvider:FC = ({children}) => {
    const {isAuthenticated } = useUserState()
    const StatusProvider = isAuthenticated ? AuthVerificationStatusProvider : UnAuthStatusProvider ;
   return <StatusProvider>{ children }</StatusProvider> 
}
```

This implementation is currently working, though it does not look that good to me.
Any ideas on this topic or any suggestions I would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not actually do that, especially in a production code base. Switching between the Contexts' providers may cause the whole react tree to re-render.

You can instead either:

1. Combine the 2 contexts into a single context and differentiate the data in the `value` prop using some kind of a flag. Or...
2. Use both contexts in your application and each context can have a flag in their `value` to denote if that context's value is valid or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have followed the first option (1) before. But i just thought that somehow this would be something that might work. Thank you once again for the clarification :)